# What happens if a magnetar collapses into a black hole?

Tags: black-holes, magnetic-fields, astrophysics, neutron-stars

Assume there is a neutron star with a magnetic field and no net electrical
charge. What happens to the magnetic field if it gains some mass and
collapses into a black hole?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

[This paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1109.0584) by Lyutikov and McKinney describes this precise scenario.   I'll provide a brief summary of their results here.

---

One of the crucial underlying assumptions made when deriving the [no-hair theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/No-hair_theorem) is that the region outside the event horizon is a vacuum.  However, a rapidly spinning, magnetized neutron star can induce vacuum breakdown, leading to the existence of self-generated currents in the magnetosphere.  That is, an initial spinning dipole field with no external currents evolves into a magnetized black hole supported by currents outside the event horizon.  In particular, rotation-induced poloidal currents cause magnetic field lines which originate near the poles of magnetar to "open up" to infinity.

The presence of a conductive plasma in the magnetosphere freezes magnetic field lines into the surface.  As the magnetar collapses, the closed field lines are absorbed into the event horizon.  However, the open lines, which connect the magnetar surface to infinity, persist and end up connecting the event horizon to infinity.  The resulting field relaxes to a split monopole configuration which looks something like this:

[image]

Over time, the equatorial current sheet dissipates and the field lines which are anchored to the event horizon are able to "slide off" and the magnetic field decays.  However, this process relies on the finite resistivity of the plasma in the magnetosphere, and is slow when compared to the timescale one would naively expect from the no-hair theorem.  As a result, magnetized black holes can persist for quite a while even in the absence of externally supplied accretion material.

Comment: This is a truly fascinating story +1! Would it be correct to say that it is a pure speculation with no experimental evidence whatsoever? It all seems to stem from the assumption that "*a rapidly spinning, magnetized neutron star can induce vacuum breakdown*". Can it really? Has a vacuum breakdown by anything spinning been ever observed? Or can it rather be taking a mathematical model of reality beyond its limits of applicability?

Comment: @safesphere The instability of the vacuum outside a rapidly spinning black hole in the presence of a strong magnetic field was explored in a 1977 paper by Blandford and Znejek, and appears to be on fairly firm theoretical footing. My guess is that there is no conclusive observational evidence of this effect yet, but I cannot speak to that with any degree of confidence.

Comment: so I think I heard you say that the elusive monopole can be formed by the collapse of a magnetar into a black hole...

Comment: @Michael Not a monopole - a *split* monopole.  Note the directions of the field lines attached to the north hemisphere vs. the south hemisphere.

Comment: Right, but can't these be considered as separate monopoles due to the discontinuity at the event horizon?  Or are they still connected somehow?

Comment: @Michael The magnetic field inside the event horizon isn't zero, if that's what you mean.

Comment: For an outside observer the event horizon takes an infinite amount of time to form. Would they still see the magnetic field dissipate?

Comment: Is this based on GUTs or some ideas merging electromagnetism and GR?

Comment: @DavidTonhofer No GUTs here, this is just classical GR + electromagnetism.

Comment: @Andrew An outside observer would quickly see an *apparent* horizon, to which the magnetic field lines would be attached.  From there, the dissipation would proceed in finite time.

Answer (score 8):

Magnetars are neutron stars where the extremely strong magnetic field originates from something called the magnetohydrodynamic process in the turbulent extremely dense superconducting fluid, that persist even after the neutron star settles into equilibrium.

> These fields then persist due to persistent currents in a proton-superconductor phase of matter that exists at an intermediate depth within the neutron star (where neutrons predominate by mass).

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetar

You are asking what would happen after the magnetar would collapse into a Black Hole  (actually it needs to gain stress-energy, not mass). I will assume you are asking about a Kerr Black Hole, that is, one that has no magnetic field officially.

Now after the collapse, the new Black Hole would have no magnetic field, that is, outside the Event Horizon, we could not observe any magnetic field. The characteristics of the Black Hole would still be describable by the Kerr metric.

It is very important that the answer to this question depends upon the source of the magnetar's magnetic field. Since that is based on the structure (and internal magnetohydrodynamic processes) of the magnetar, that would be destroyed as the extreme levels of gravity would win over the magnetar's internal structure to the lowest level, the magnetar's inside magnetohydrodynamic structure would eventually be torn into its elementary constituents.

So the answer to your question is that after the collapse, there would be no magnetic field observable outside the Event Horizon.

Just a note, officially, we do not have a clear declaration as of today whether Black Holes themselves could have magnetic fields, though, we have detected magnetic fields around Sagittarius A, near the event horizon, the source of these might just be the accretion disk and not the Black Hole itself.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_hole#cite_note-152

So officially, Kerr type Black Holes do not have a magnetic field, and the fact that the original (before the collapse) astrophysical object is a magnetar does not change this.

Comment: Although this is a similar question, I'm not asking what would happen if a magnetar and a black hole merge. I'm asking what would happen to a magnetar if it simply gained some mass (i.e. meteorite impact) and it's gravitational force became large enough for it to collapse into a black hole.

Comment: @Andrew oh you are correct, let me edit, but the answer is that it would gain an EH, which, means, that gravity inside would reach such extreme levels, that the magnetohydrodynamic structure would be destroyed, causing the magnetic field to cease.

Comment: Suggestion: Clarify that BH means black hole and EH means event horizon. These are not standard acronyms.

Comment: @G.Smith  thank you I edited, I wrote them out everywhere.

Comment: @G.Smith, please help me understand- is the reason that a black hole which formed from a magnetized object has no magnetic field because in the process of collapsing, the   field-generating mechanism of the object is destroyed? And should I post this as a question myself? I'm very confused here!

Comment: @nielsnielsen I don’t understand magnetar collapse. I just know that if the result is a black hole with spin but no charge, then the magnetic field has to go away somehow.

Comment: @nielsnielsen "*is the reason that a black hole which formed from a magnetized object has no magnetic field because in the process of collapsing, the field-generating mechanism of the object is destroyed?*" - Yes, exactly, squashed by gravity. The magnetic field is generated by different charges moving differently, much like the field of an electromagnet, which itself is electrically neutral. Now, put the electromagnet under a powerful hydraulic press…

Comment: `You are asking what would happen after the magnetar would collapse into a Black Hole, I will assume you are asking about a Kerr Black Hole, that is, one that has no magnetic field officially.`  I'm not understanding why you would assume a black hole without a magnetic field when the definition of a magnetar seems to be "a type of neutron star believed to have an extremely powerful magnetic field"

Comment: @Michael in practice, astronomically, the Kerr metric is the one that is useful mostly. There are other metrics, like the Kerr-Newman, but astronomically, it is not really useful. So far, the observations and experiments all show no significant magnetic field for the BH itself. There are weak magnetic fields, but they are probably generated by the accretion disk matter.

Comment: @Michael The reason is the [no-hair theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/No-hair_theorem).  In the absence of external matter, the only parameters which characterize a black hole are its mass, angular momentum, and charge.  In the absence of net charge, the black hole is of Kerr type, which does not support a magnetic field.  You need external matter for that.